# Why is there an unexpected token error when creating object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, node-request

My scenario is that I am trying to add headers to a node request object.  But I'm hung up on just creating the headers array.

```
let headers = [];
let options = {
  url: this.baseUrl + appconst.route.postMessage
};

if (token) {
  console.log(appconst.headers.authToken); // no problem here
  let authTokenHeader = { appconst.headers.authToken: token.toBase64() }; // throws
  headers.push(authTokenHeader);
}

if (msg) {
  headers.push({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
  options.body = JSON.stringify(msg);
}
```

The 'throws' line is giving...

```
  let authTokenHeader = { appconst.headers.authToken: token.toBase64() };
                                  ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Can you please help me understand what is going on here?  I am very confused because the "const.headers.authToken" is defined and the line above it works fine.  Yes, I am very new to JavaScript.

Comment: You shouldn’t use `const` as a variable name.

Comment: If you really want to use `const.headers.authToken` as the key name of your object, your need to wrap it between quote: `"const.headers.authToken"`

Comment: Sorry. It's not const in the actual code. I just changed it for the question to obfuscate not realizing that introduces another bug. My bad. I will update the question.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate of what @CBroe posted.  I corrected my code by bracketing appconst.headers.authToken using the EMAScript 2015 computed property names notation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer.

Answer (score 0):

`const` - is reserved keyword.
Simply pick another one for your needs.

**UPDATE:**

So as far as we are using `appconst`, not `const` - there is another problem: you try to assign nested properties.
There are two workarounds. First you create object literal like this:

```
let authTokenHeader = { 
  appconst: {
    headers: {
      authToken: token.toBase64() 
    }
  }
};
```

Another one is to create nested properties like this:

```
let authTokenHeader = {};
```

And then you assign properties:

```
authTokenHeader.appconst = {
  headers: {
    authToken: token.toBase64() 
  }
};
```

Once I saw another wierd way of defining properties, but as far as we all want our codes to be readable - let us leave things as is.

Comment: Lol dang. Question fail for me. It's actually not const in code. I changed it for the question to obfuscate a proprietary name. I'll fix the question.

Comment: @RichAmberale I've update my answer.